# Redmine plugin for Jenkins: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Tags: jenkins, redmine-api

I am rethrieving the next error in Jenkins when trying to get Redmine Metrics:

```
hudson.plugins.redmine.MetricsException: com.taskadapter.redmineapi.RedmineFormatException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
Build step 'Aggregate Redmine ticket metrics' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea of what could cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your jenkins server run below command as jenkins user

   ```
   ping X.X.X.X(IPADDRESS OF REDMINE)
   ```
2. Also check whether given URL for redmine is correct in jenkins.

   > Manage jenkins -->> configure sydtem -->> Redmine -->> Base url -->>
   >   http://X.X.X.X(or)Domain_Name
3. Then paste your redmine server api-key in

   > Project -->> configure -->> Post-build Actions -->> Aggregate Redmine ticket metrics